# Preventing Immediate Execution of Functions Pushed to an Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to push functions into an array in JavaScript and then execute them using Promise.all(). However, I noticed that the functions are being immediately called when I push them into the array. How can I prevent the immediate execution of functions and ensure they are executed only when using Promise.all()?

Here's a simplified example of my code:

```
 prices.map(price => {
    const minPrice = minPrices.find(_price => _price.TYPE === price.TYPE)
    if (minPrice) {
      parentChanges.push(changePrice(mainProduct.ID, minPrice.PRICE, minPrice.TYPE))
    }
    childChanges.push( changePrice(id, price.PRICE, price.TYPE))
  })
  await Promise.all(childChanges)
  await Promise.all(parentChanges)
```

```
export async function changePrice(id, price, type) {
  const lastPriceData = (await repo.raw(`some query to get last price data`))[0]
  if (lastPriceData && price !== lastPriceData.PRICE) {
        await db.sequelize.query('some query to apply price changes in product_prices and order_products tables')
   
  }
  else if (!lastPriceData) {
     await db.sequelize.query('some query to add new price in product_prices table ')
  }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: @VLAZ I want to store functions in the tasks array and then execute them concurrently using Promise.all(tasks). However, in the code example I shared, the functions are being immediately called when I push them into the array.

Comment: Yes, async functions *are* immediately called. And Even if you store them to execute them later you'd get the exact same behaviour - you'd have to call them one by one and then pass the promises to `Promise.all()`. This is consistent with how async functions work anyway - they aren't executed "in parallel" (although the underlying async operation might then be concurrent). The question is *what is the problem*? Because the solution might be as trivial as "You literally have to do nothing, that's how async works". Or you may need to bundle and run them in a different way. Again: what is X?

Comment: "*ensure they are executed only when using Promise.all()*" - this does not make sense. `Promise.all` does not execute functions. It expects an array of promises, which *you* have to construct by calling the functions, before passing it to `Promise.all`.

Comment: When I use console.log to view my tasks, I can see that promises have been added to the array, but they are still pending. This is what my log looks like: "tasks: [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]". @Bergi

Comment: @VLAZ, I have an array of product prices with various types, and each product has a parent with a minimum price for each type based on its child prices. I want to update these prices by using the "changePrice" function in the first array, then selecting the minimum price for each type. If the child price is greater than the current parent price, I will push the "changePrice" function for the parent. After mapping through the array, I will execute "Promise.all()" for the array of child changes and then call for the parent changes.

Comment: I made changes to the main code snip in the question. @VLAZ

Comment: Maybe you should include the `changePrice` function so we can see if it actually returns a Promise? Also, your question text says "how te prevent immediate execution of functions". This question has been answered below by several of the answers.

Comment: sure but changePrice is a Promise because async functions already return a Promise 
I have included the `changePrice` function in the question. @Kokodoko

Comment: And what happens if you explicitly return the result of the query? Something like: `let result = await db.sequelize.query(...)` followed by `return result`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the functions are immediately called and executed because you are invoking them directly when pushing them into the tasks array. To prevent immediate execution and ensure they are executed only when using `Promise.all()`, you need to pass the function references instead of invoking them.

Example:

```
  let tasks = [];

  tasks.push(() => changePrice(1, 1, 1, 1));
  tasks.push(() => changePrice(2, 2, 2, 2));
  tasks.push(() => changePrice(3, 3, 3, 3));
  tasks.push(() => changePrice(4, 4, 4, 4));

  console.log('tasks:', tasks);
  await Promise.all(tasks.map(task => task()));
```

Comment: Exactly. That's why I was trying not to do extra work, i.e. not to map the tasks array in Promise.all().
Is there no other way to optimize it?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled how much more optimized you want it to be? You have functions that are not immediately executed (this is what you asked for in the question), and you have one line of code that puts all the returned promises into the `Promise.all`...

Answer (score 0):

> How can I prevent the immediate execution of functions and ensure they are executed only when using `Promise.all()`?

You can't. `Promise.all` does not execute functions. It expects an array of promises, which you have to construct by calling the functions, *before* passing it to `Promise.all`.

If what you actually want is to defer the execution of the functions until the first `Promise.all` has finished, you should write

```
const childChanges = prices.map(price => {
  return changePrice(id, price.PRICE, price.TYPE);
});
await Promise.all(childChanges)

const parentChanges = prices.map(price => {
  const minPrice = minPrices.find(_price => _price.TYPE === price.TYPE)
  if (minPrice) {
    return changePrice(mainProduct.ID, minPrice.PRICE, minPrice.TYPE);
  }
});
await Promise.all(parentChanges);
```

However, I don't see a reason in your code why they would need to wait, you could easily run all of them concurrently:

```
const changes = [];
for (const price of prices) {
  const minPrice = minPrices.find(_price => _price.TYPE === price.TYPE)
  if (minPrice) {
    changes.push(changePrice(mainProduct.ID, minPrice.PRICE, minPrice.TYPE));
  }
  changes.push(changePrice(id, price.PRICE, price.TYPE));
}
await Promise.all(changes);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but even if I use a single array called "changes", I still encounter the same problem. This is because the function runs immediately when I push to the array before Promise.all. Although I can see that the promises have been added to the array through console.log, they remain pending. As shown in my log, the current state of the "changes" array is: "changes: [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]".

Comment: @MelikaShojaee Of course `changes` is an array of promises, and of course they would be pending if you log them before the `await`. But that is not a problem! What results do you need that the code does not have?

Comment: I am facing a major issue where the promises continue to execute despite commenting out `await Promise.all().` Upon adding some logs to the code, I noticed that the promises are being executed before the `await Promise.all()` call, which is not what I intended. My goal was to store all the promises in an array and run them in parallel once the storing process is complete. It's worth noting that the `pending` status indicates that the calls were made before the Promise.all() call, and the promises are running immediately as soon as I push them into the array @Bergi.

Comment: "*run them once the storing process is complete*" - as I pointed out in my answer, that is impossible. But it doesn't really matter! The result is indistinguishable, your code works, the `await`ed `Promise.all(…)` returns the same value regardless.

Comment: Btw, promises don't "execute", they represent results. It's the functions that are executing, and they start executing when you call them. Comment *them* out if you don't want them to execute. I don't see why that would be a "major issue"

Comment: I'm having some difficulty communicating my thoughts effectively to you. As part of a test, I commented out "await Promise.all". The main issue I'm encountering is that I'd like to save promises and execute them at a later time. However, when I add each promise to an array, they execute right away.Do you mean Is it not possible to store promises without immediate execution and then call them using "Promise.all" after the storing process? @Bergi

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying: it is impossible. A promise is nothing that gets executed or can be called. That's what functions are for. If you wanted to store something to execute later, use an array of functions, as in the answers below. However, in the code you've shown, there is absolutely no need to do that. Just move the code of the `changePrice` to where you want them to be made, like in the first snippet in my answer.

Comment: I understand. I think in a similar situation, the only solution is to use an array of functions, as suggested in the answers below. Thank you very much. @Bergi